# PostgreSQL 9.6.9 on Alpine Linux (arm32v6) in Docker container - how to install correct postgresql-contrib package?

Tags: postgresql, docker, arm, alpine-linux, postgresql-9.6

I need to install PostgreSQL 9.6.9 with uuid-ossp support in a Docker container on a 32-bit ARM system (its a QNAP NAS, CPU: Annapurna Labs Alpine AL-314).

I found the [arm32v6/postgres](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v6/postgres/) images and installed `arm32v6/postgres:9.6.9-alpine`. This is working smoothly, but lacks the postgresql-contrib package. As far as I understand, I need to install postgresql-contrib to get uuid-ossp support.

I opened a CLI in the container and tried:

```
# apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/armhf/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/armhf/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.7.0-215-g16971064c0 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main]
v3.7.0-207-gac61833f9b [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community]
OK: 8879 distinct packages available
# apk add postgresql-contrib=9.6.9-r0
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  postgresql-contrib-10.4-r0:
    breaks: world[postgresql-contrib=9.6.9-r0]
```

How can I install the correct version of postgresql-contrib? Or can I just use postgresql-contrib-10.4-r0 with PostgreSQL 9.6.9?

Answer (score 8):

Just use base alpine image and install PostgreSQL completely from Alpine's official packages: `postgresql` and `postgresql-contrib`.  The last stable Alpine providing PostgreSQL 9.6 is v3.6, which is two versions behind, but still supported. Alpine v3.7 provides only 10.4.

Also don't specify exact version to `apk add`. Alpine provides only single version of the package per branch (e.g. v3.7, v3.8, edge). Once we release postgresql-contrib 9.6.9-r1 or 9.6.10-r0 (e.g. fixing some security issue), 9.6.9-r0 will not be available anymore and your `apk add postgresql-contrib=9.6.9-r0` will fail.

These specialized Docker images “packaging” something that is already properly packaged in Alpine are mostly totally useless and just causes confusions and problems. I can't even count how many times I'm responding to this type of issue on SO.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Installing `postgresql` and `postgresql-contrib` has its own issues. E.g. postgres' `initdb` command has some issue with a missing locale. I found out that the arm32v6/postgres image does in fact have uuid-ossp support out of the box.

Comment: in short: 
`apk add postgresql` 
`apk add postgresql-contrib`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the [`arm32v6/postgres:9.6.9-alpine` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v6/postgres/) does have uuid-ossp support out of the box. The image seems to be compiled with (some?) postgres-contrib modules. A look into [the Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/34689e2a5ba1841fb09fd5a9c29ef47a022d48dc/9.6/alpine/Dockerfile) might help.